# Por que métodos estáticos podem ser chamados através da "instância" da classe em Python 3?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x

Digamos que eu tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class Person:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print('Hello!)
```

Ao realizar a operação `Person().hello()` o método é executado normalmente. Mas o método `hello` pertence à classe Person, não à uma instância da classe. Alguém saberia me dizer o porquê essa instrução funciona?

Comment: Acredito que caia no de sempre "porque os criadores da linguagem acharam que assim era útil". Pode ser que não quiseram complicar o compilador. Pode até ser, embora improvável, que não se atentaram nisso. Há quem ache que isto não é bom porque não sassa a intenção correta. Batendo o olho parece que é um método de instância. Mas em linguagens como Python, não se preocupa muito com isto. Por exemplo, você não sabe se `Person() é um o construtor do objeto ou uma função qualquer. A linguagem não se preocupa com mostrar a intenção de forma mais clara ,então isso é considerado normal nela.

Comment: Estranhamente, em Java também é possível chamar métodos estáticos através de instâncias

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co), Jon Skeet diz que acredita que foi um erro dos desenvolvedores do Java, talvez isso também se aplique a Python (não me atrevo a colocar isso como resposta haha)

Comment: O que eu acho estranho é que em todo método não estático em Python, a própria instância é passado como primeiro parâmetro do método (self). Sendo que o método hello não recebe nenhum parâmetro, sendo assim isso já deveria causar um erro.

Comment: Não conheço muito sobre as particularidades de Python, mas esse self não é passado de qualquer maneira? Assim como temos os `arguments` em JavaScript

Comment: O self (que na verdade é o objeto que está tentando acessar o método) é passado implicitamente para todos os métodos. Pode ser que nos métodos estáticos isso não aconteça, mais uma dúvida que tenho.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isso tem, de certa forma, relação com os atributos de instância e classe, junto com a construção da linguagem Python, mais precisamente os decoradores. Diferente de outras linguagens, a definição de um método estático - ou de classe, usando `@classmethod` - se dá através de um decorador, não de uma palavra-chave da linguagem. O que isso muda? Muda que ao utilizar um decorador sobre um método, a referência a este método não é acessível diretamente, pois o retorno do decorador é uma função - e é esta função que invoca a referência do método. Você pode confirmar isso fazendo:

```
class Person:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print('Hello!')

print(type(Person.hello))
print(type(Person().hello))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/y4AfuS) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MUql/0)</sup>

A saída será:

```
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
```

E não `method`, como seria o esperado. Para entender melhor o comportamento, basta lembrarmos do funcionamento de um decorador: uma função que retorna outra outra função (a grosso modo). Tanto que é possível chamar o decorador de forma explícita.

```
class Person:
    def __hello():
        print('Hello!')
    hello = staticmethod(__hello)
```

Esse código, para fins práticos, é o equivalente ao anterior, que utiliza o `@staticmethod`, porém nesse fica claro que o que é criado é um atributo de classe chamado `hello`, que é uma função, retorno do decorador. Sendo um atributo de classe, ele será, também, acessível nas instâncias - e como é um atributo de classe, ele mantém a referência ao mesmo objeto tanto na classe quanto na instância. Podemos confirmar isso verificando o `id` de cada um:

```
class Person:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print('Hello!')

print(id(Person.hello))
print(id(Person().hello))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bBCL7m) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MUsW/0)</sup>

A saída é algo como:

```
47914624982008
47914624982008
```

O que indica que os objetos acessados pela classe ou pela instância são exatamente os mesmos.

**E por quê não é passado `self` por parâmetro?**

Justamente porque o objeto não aponta para um método, mas sim para uma função (que é o retorno do decorador). O primeiro parâmetro, `self`, é definido implicitamente na chamada de um método pelo Python, porém, como nesse caso o que ocorre é a chamada de uma função - e é a função que invoca o método - não é passado tal parâmetro (até porque não faz sentido acessar uma instância em um método estático).

Podemos imaginar o `staticmethod` como sendo algo como:

```
def staticmethod(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Perceba que na chamada de `func`, que seria a invocação (<strike>do mal</strike>) do método, não há nenhum parâmetro equivalente ao `self` sendo passado.

**Mas e se precisar acessar atributos da classe?**

Se dentro do método é necessário acessar os atributos de classe não é de um método estático que precisamos, mas sim de um método de classe. Diferente do método estático, o método de classe recebe como primeiro parâmetro um objeto que é a referência à própria classe:

```
class Person:
    attr = "SOpt"

    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        print('Hello', cls.attr)
```

Isso acontece porque, diferente do `@staticmethod`, no `@classmethod` há a passada da classe como primeiro parâmetro. Seria algo como:

```
def classmethod(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        classObject = inspect.get_glass(func) # hipotético
        func(classObject, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Bem explicado, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Creio que isto seja porque o `@staticmethod` apenas não transforma o primeiro argumento do método em "`self`", por exemplo se tentar algo como:

```
class Person:
    x = 1

    def foo(self, bar):
        x = bar

    @staticmethod
    def hello(self):
        print(self.x)

p = Person()
p.foo(2017)
p.hello()
```

Vai causar o erro:

> TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Já que Python não tem visibilidade (`public`, `private`, `protected`) então é possível acessar externamente a variáveis e métodos, outro detalhe é que seria possivel usar em outras linguagens também (o que varia de linguagem para linguagens, algumas emitem warnings outras não aceitam), exemplo em PHP que aceita:

```
<?php
class Person {
    static function hello() {
        print('Olá');
    }
}

$p = new Person();
$p->hello();
```

Já em C# isso causaria problema de acesso, por exemplo:

```
class Exemplo {
    public int foo() { return 1; }
    public static int bar() { return 42; }
}

Exemplo exemplo = new Exemplo();
Console.WriteLine(exemplo.foo());
Console.WriteLine(exemplo.bar());
```

> Static member `Exemplo.bar()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Então em `static` não parece ser um erro acessar diretamente na instancia (dependendo da linguagem), desde que não seja possível acessar o "self".

---

### Como o `self` funciona no método

Então voltando ao Python e pra resumir, o que diferencia é o acesso a instancia, dentro do `@staticmethod` o primeiro argumento de um método não será o `self`, por exemplo se passar isto:

```
class Bar:
    def foo(maracuja, baz=None):
        print(maracuja)
        print(baz)

Bar().foo('teste')
```

Vai exibir algo como:

> ```
> <__main__.Bar object at 0x02061150>
> teste
> ```

Então `self` pode ser escrito de qualquer maneira, que o primeiro argumento do método sempre será *"o acesso a instancia"* (o `self`), agora se passar `@staticmethod` o primeiro argumento será um argumento de fato, por exemplo:

```
class Bar:
    @staticmethod
    def foo(maracuja, baz=None):
        print(maracuja)
        print(baz)

Bar().foo('teste')
```

Será exibido:

> ```
> teste
> None
> ```

Acessar `Bar().foo()` ou `Bar.foo()` terá o mesmo nível de acesso, ou seja não acessam a instancia, a escrita é independente e não afeta, provavelmente por decisão de design da linguagem.

Comment: A palavra self não é uma palavra reservada, ela é usada apenas por convenção. O que importa é o que ela significa: a instância. O self é passado implicitamente para todos os métodos não estáticos, logo, neste seu exemplo, o self é só mais um argumento comum e como você não passou esse argumento na hora da chamada do método ele acusou o erro. Resumindo, tu tem um método esperando um argumento mas tu chamou ele sem nenhum, logo, uma exceção é levantada. Se você passar qualquer argumento que tenha a propriedade x, o código funcionará perfeitamente.

Comment: @flpn `self` *implicito* em Python? Será que estamos falando da mesma linguagem? Estou quase certo de que `self` é obrigatório nos métodos usados na instancia. PS: uso Python 3.6. De qualquer forma vou dar uma lida melhor na documentação.

Comment: Sim, o primeiro parâmetro (`self`, ou qualquer outro nome que queira dar) é **passado implicitamente** mas é **recebido explicitamente**. Por isso ao chamarmos um método não precisamos passar o parâmetro self, mas ao declarar um método nós temos que necessariamente colocá-lo na lista de parâmetros.

Comment: @flpn então imagine um método **sem** `staticmethod` assim `def baz(x):` qual vai ser o valor de `x`? Ele vai ser algo como: `<__main__.Person object at 0x002B6350>`, ou seja vc pode escrever `self`, ou `xyz` que vai ser a mesma coisa. A unica maneira de impedir o `self` (independente do nome)  é usar `staticmethod`, deu pra entender?

Comment: Sim, mas eu não discordei disso em nenhum momento. Só que eu não entendi como isso pode sanar a minha dúvida.

Comment: @flpn porque se "sem" staticmethod o primeiro argumento vira o "self", com staticmethod o primeiro argumento **não** vira o "self", sendo assim, esse é o uso do staticmethod. Entendeu? Agora sobre o `Foo().bar()` funcionar eu mencionei na resposta, é porque ele continuará sendo estático e será a mesma coisa que `Foo.bar()`, pois em nenhum deles será possivel acessar self.

Answer (score 1):

Métodos de classe marcados com `@staticmethod` são considerados estáticos, ou seja, não dependem de uma instância do objeto para serem chamados.

Porém, isso não significa que chamar métodos estáticos por meio de uma instância do objeto seja inválido.

Como métodos estáticos não dependem de uma instância do objeto para serem chamados, a auto-referência `self` não é repassada para o método e nem é válida dentro do escopo de métodos estáticos.

Considere a seguinte classe:

```
class Cachorro:

    def __init__( self, nome ):
        self.nome = nome;
        print("Cachorro construido!")

    def obterNome(self):
        return self.nome;

    @staticmethod
    def latir():   # Metodos estaticos nao possuem a auto-referencia 'self'
        print("!Au! au!");
```

Testes:

```
c = Cachorro("Astro")      # Criando instancia de Cachorro

c.latir()                  # OK! Apesar de estatico, latir() pode ser chamado a partir de uma instancia de Cachorro

print c.obterNome()        # OK! O metodo obterNome() NAO EH estatico.

Cachorro.latir()           # OK! O metodo latir() eh estatico.

print Cachorro.obterNome() # ERRO! O metodo obterNome() NAO EH estatico.
```